# How can I shorten this algorithm for finding Prime Numbers?

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, numbers, primes

Just wondering if anyone could help me on this. 
The code is working but
Is it possible to shorten/remove some unnecessary code from this Algorithim while keeping its method 
the same? I have already taken out some things I don't need but am unsure if anything else can be taken out.

Thanks in advance!

```
public static void listPrimes(int maxNum) {
    for (int i = 2; i < maxNum; i++) {   
        boolean isprime = true;   

        for (int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++) {   
            if (i > 1 && j < i && i % j == 0) {   
                isprime = false;   
                break;   
            }
        }   

        if (isprime) {
            System.out.println(i); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: `i` will always be greater than 1. and `j` will always be less than `i` since its max value is `Math.sqrt(i)`.

Comment: This is a strange question. Do you just want fewer lines for it's own sake? Do you not know how it works? Do you not trust it?

Comment: You might consider [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for this question.

Comment: Generally speaking, questions along the lines of "Can you improve this working code somehow?" don't belong on SO. See Telthien's comment.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what you mean, I will look at coderview. I was just getting some second opinions on the efficeny etc of the code while still using the sqrt method.

Comment: And yes gabe I was also considering conditions which would cause the code to fail. Thank you for you're help guys

Comment: @user2247526 since you're new to the site, use `@<username>` to send a message in your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is not to shorten, rather to speed up. Also note that there are more efficient methods for finding prime numbers.

Apart from outputting the value, `Math.sqrt(i)` is probably the most expensive operation (as soon as the numbers start getting large, it will probably take an increasingly greater percentage of the processing time), you may want to consider putting it into a variable before the loop.

Only 2 and uneven numbers are prime, so you can hard-code 2 and skip all even numbers.

`i > 1 && j < i` is pointless as already mentioned.

SHORTEN - You replace `isPrime` with just checking `j`.

```
public static void listPrimes(int maxNum) {
    System.out.println(2);
    for (int i = 3; i < maxNum; i += 2) {   
        int sqrtI = (int)Math.sqrt(i);
        int j;
        for (j = 2; j <= sqrtI; j++)
            if (i % j == 0)
                break;   

        if (j == sqrtI + 1)
            System.out.println(i); 
    } 
}
```